# Is there a way to detect that a method is being overridden before actually running the code?

Tags: python, methods, overriding, typechecking

Is there a way to type check that a method is being overridden by a class member in python?

For example, when the `main` is invoked in the following code, it gives the error that "'`NoneType`' object is not callable". The reference to `repository.records` is evaluating to the attribute rather than the method. It would be nice to be able to detect this before actually running the code.

```
class Repository():
    """Test method overload.
    """
    def __init__(
        self,            
    ) -> None:
        """Instantiate the repository.            
        """            
        self.records = None
    
    def records(self):
        return []

def main():
    repository = Repository()    
    print(repository.records())
```

Answer (score 1):

Discovered that this can be detected at run time using `mypy`.

```
poetry run -m mypy src
```

produces this output

```
pythonissue/main.py:11: error: Incompatible types in assignment (expression has type "None", variable has type "Callable[[], Any]")
```

Answer (score -1):

There is probably a way to do this directly... but you could use `repr`. It returns a representation of the object that can be parsed to determine inheritance.

```py
class AbstractRepository(ABC):
    
    @abstractmethod
    def get(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
    
    def records(self):
        return "I'm from the Abstract Repository"

class ConcreteRepository(AbstractRepository):
    
    def get(self):
        return "Here is your dataz"

repo = ConcreteRepository()
```

We can then access the inheritance details like this:

`repr(repo.get).split(" ")[2]  # So very ugly but it works.`

This will return `ConcreteRepository.get`

Comment: The question was to "*detect this before actually running the code.*"

Comment: @GinoMempin: It's not clear that that's an actual requirement. Before your edit changed the question, detecting the error before running was only listed as something that would be "nice", not an explicit requirement.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica The 1st sentence of the [original version of the question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/69890455/1) (and untouched by my edit) contains: "*Is there a way to type check that a method is over ridden by a class member in python?*".

Comment: @GinoMempin: Yeah, but that doesn't require a pre-runtime solution. They didn't say "statically" or anything like that.